# 'SliderInput' is not exported from '@mui/material/Slider' (imported as 'SliderInput') even though it is marked as exported from Slider.d.ts file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

I want to create Slider custom component and make my custom InputComponent to add there tooltip when hover some range of values. o do that I imported SliderInput from "@mui/material/Slider" as below:

```js
import Slider, { SliderInput } from "@mui/material/Slider";
```

When I press F12 and go to implementation it shows up in Slider.d.ts file:

```js
...
export const SliderMark: React.FC<SliderMarkProps>;
...
export const SliderInput: React.FC<SliderInputProps>;
...
```

SliderMark from which I also created custom control was exported correctly.

This is the error I've got:

```js
export 'SliderInput' (imported as 'SliderInput') was not found in '@mui/material/Slider' (possible exports: SliderMark, SliderMarkLabel, SliderRail, SliderRoot, SliderThumb, SliderTrack, SliderValueLabel, default, sliderClasses)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created [an issue at github](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33992). It is a bug. Here is the response from one of developers:

> We don't export SliderInput from @mui/material. It should be removed from Slider.d.ts - this was likely omitted by mistake. Slider gets a plain input in its Input slot, so there's nothing to export.